# Why `ls` list multiple files per line, but `ls pipe/redirect` list just 1 file per line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Just curious, this is normal-expected behavior of `ls`:

```
user@host:~$ ls
Codes    Documents  Music   Pictures  Templates
Desktop  Downloads  Papers  Public    Videos
```

But when I use `ls` with pipe/redirection, it behave like `ls -1`:

```
user@host:~$ ls | cat
Codes
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Music
Papers
Pictures
Public
Templates
Videos
```

Why? (and how to write such program that gives difference output between stdout and pipe like this?)

---

P.S. I also set `alias l='ls -F'`, and this time pipe/redirection is no longer `ls -1` style:

```
user@host:~$ l | cat
Codes/    Documents/  Music/   Pictures/  Templates/
Desktop/  Downloads/  Papers/  Public/    Videos/
```

Without using the alias, it does the command in `ls -1` style, however:

```
$ ls -F | cat
Codes/
Desktop/
Documents/
Downloads/
Music/
Papers/
Pictures/
Public/
Templates/
Videos/
```

Comment: invoke `info coreutils 'General output formatting'` in the terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check this line from the [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c#n1678):

```
if (format == long_format)
  format = (isatty (STDOUT_FILENO) ? many_per_line : one_per_line);
```

It uses the [isatty](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty) function to check if `stdout` points to a tty, and to print `many_per_line` if it does or `one_per_line` if it does not.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how GNU `ls` does it ([ls.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/ls.c;h=1652bcf94314c29e8444bfe9a6fe250e1ec0846e;hb=da398ae5dfa43efda48310899c24242da4764f44#l1545)):

```
  if (isatty (STDOUT_FILENO))
    {
      format = many_per_line;
    }
  else
    {
      format = one_per_line;
    }
```